# Ubuntu 23.10 - I can't run the Ubuntu installer on my PC

Tags: system-installation

I have a modern PC with the latest components on the market. My motherboard is a MSI MAG Z790 TOMAHAWK WIFI. When I try to install Ubuntu, I get the error shown in the image. How can I fix it?

[image: Error: nouveau unknown chipset]

My PC has the following characteristics:

[image: PC Specs]

**SOLVED**: I had only to run it in Safe mode, after that I could run and install everything without problems, even the drivers for the 4090 got automatically installed without issues.

Comment: What version/flavor of Ubuntu. MSI Z790
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494277&p=14175061#post14175061
 ASUS PRIME Z790-P WIFI motherboard.
https://www.phoronix.com/review/intel-14600k-14900k-linux

Comment: I had only to run it in Safe mode, after that I could run and install everything without problems, even the drivers for the 4090 got automatically installed without issues.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and accept it, helping others and gaining some reputation in the process.