Ubuntu 24.04 USB Install (UEFI)
While installing Ubuntu 24.04 via USB in UEFI mode, when it tries to read the USB, I get the following error:
Initramfs unpacking failed: invalid magic at start of compressed archive
I have to restart the system. I didn't encounter this issue in previous versions, but I'm facing it in this version as well as related distributions like Kubuntu and the latest Mint. I downloaded the ISO several times and used different tools to create the bootable USB, like Etcher and the built-in USB creator in Ubuntu and Mint, but the issue persists.
Help me!

Did you verify the ISO you downloaded? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

All Linux distributions based on Ubuntu 24.04, such as the latest versions of Mint and Kubuntu, have this issue. I’ve downloaded them all from their official websites. This problem does not occur in older versions or in other distributions like Fedora or openSUSE, so it cannot be related to verification.

That was not what I asked you.

Please read the answers at the following location. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1516006/booting-24-04-from-usb-with-uefi-fails-with-initramfs-unpacking-failed-and-k

Are you using the latest 24.04.1 which has some major fixes. Also is UEFI & SSD firmware the latest version available?

Yes bro , 24.04.1

This question is similar to: Booting 24.04 from USB with UEFI fails with: "Initramfs unpacking failed" and "Kernel panic". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
